# Find the limit of $f(n)$ where $f(n)=(2-f(n+1))^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to[0,2]$ such that $f(1)=2$ and:

$$f(n)=(2-f(n+1))^2\qquad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$

Prove that the limit of $f(n)$ as $n\to\infty$ exists and show it is equal to $1$; namely:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=1$$

I couldn't figure out how to prove the limit exists. Usually when I encounter these recursion relations I try to prove that $f(n)$ is bounded and monotonic, but after substituting some values of $n$ I realized (mayble falsley) that $f(n)$ is not monotonic at all. I'd be happy to hear your thoughts.

- Assuming the limit exists, I think I know how to prove it is equal to $1$ - All I need to do is to solve the equation $L=(2-L)^2$. The solutions are $L=4$ (not possible since $f(n)\leq2$) and $L=1$ (which is the solution).

Thanks

**Edit**: I did manage to show that if for some $k\in\mathbb{N}, f(k+1)\geq f(k+2)$, then also $f(k+1)\geq f(k)$. This is because:

$$f(k+1)\geq f(k+2)\iff2-\sqrt{f(k)}\geq2-\sqrt{f(k+1)}\iff f(k)\leq f(k+1)$$

Similarly, if $f(k+1)\leq f(k+2)$, then also $f(k+1)\leq f(k)$. This means that for odd values of $n$, $f(n)$ is monotonically decreasing, and for even values of $n$, $f(n)$ is monotonically increasing. $f(n)$ is obviously bounded, therefore, both the sequences $f(2n)$ and $f(2n+1)$ have a limit. The only problem I have know, is that I have to show they approach the same limit. In order to prove that, I thought maybe I should solve the following equation for $L$:

$$f(n+2)=2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{f(n)}}\implies L=2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{L}}$$

But I don't think I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to see
$$ f(n+1)=2-\sqrt{f(n)} $$
and hence
$$ |f(n+1)-1|=|1-\sqrt{f(n)}|=\frac{|f(n)-1|}{1+\sqrt{f(n)}}. $$
It is not hard to see $2-\sqrt2\le f(n)\le 2$ and so
$$ |f(n+1)-1|=\frac{|f(n)-1|}{1+\sqrt{f(n)}}\le\frac{1}{3-\sqrt2}|f(n)-1|. $$
Thus
$$ |f(n)-1|\le \frac{1}{(3-\sqrt2)^{n-1}}|f(1)-1|. $$
Letting $n\to\infty$ gives
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=1. $$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$$f(n)-1=(2-f(n+1))^2-1$$

$$=(1-f(n+1))(3-f(n+1))$$

and

$$\frac 13 \le \frac{1}{3-f(n+1)}<1$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't figure out how to continue with this

Comment: @AmitZach Find $ K\in(0,1)$ such that $ |f(n+1)-1|<K<|f(n)-1|$